# WPF app SQL connection string error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

This question has probably been asked a thousand times but all the answers that I have seen are not relevant to my question.

I have an asp.net web site setup locally to connect to sql and I used the exact same connection strings in the WPF App.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TrackingConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=RAIDSHIPPING\FRTOOLS; Initial Catalog=SHIPPING; User Id=sa; Password=password" />
    <add name="RMAConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=RAIDSHIPPING\FRTOOLS; Initial Catalog=FRTOOLSRMA; User Id=sa; Password=password" />
    <add name="PickListConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=RAIDSHIPPING\FRTOOLS; Initial Catalog=Picklist; User Id=sa; Password=password" />
    <add name="ShipWorksConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=RAIDSHIPPING\FRTOOLS; Initial Catalog=ShipWorks; User Id=sa; Password=password" />
    <add name="SupplyConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=RAIDSHIPPING\FRTOOLS; Initial Catalog=SupplyManager; User Id=sa; Password=password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

As usual this works on the local machine but on the network machine I get a  "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server." error.

Like I said this connection string is copied exactly from the asp.net web application, web.config file connection string which the network machine consumes fine.  I have the App.config properties set to Copy always also the Sql server configuration is set up to enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP.  Windows Firewall has port 1433 open. I thought the Copy always property being set would have solved the problem since the program wouldn't work because images were causing it to break until I set their properties to copy always. I've restarted the SQL Server and machine.

Comment: Your SQL Server doesn't allow remote connections. See [7 things to check to resolve  “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Comment: SQL remote connections was enabled because the asp.net web app could connect to the SQL server. No worries 2 restarts on the local machine unkinked the problem, no on too the newest one. I'm unsure what to do for the answer since it was a restart that fixed the error, but the checklist was better than the ones I found online, most likely it being a 2005 SQL server article and I was searching on 2012.

Comment: Use an IP instead of dns name, i had some small issues because of that ( just a hint though)